# Paginação de resultados com busca em dois campos

Tags: php, algoritmo-de-busca, filtro

Ola, bom dia, estou buscando ajuda pois estou tendo problemas em criar uma paginação de resultados, eu fiz uma pagina que contem dois campos de busca, "o que busca" e "onde busca", ela funciona e faz o filtro correto, porem não estou conseguindo fazer a paginação para limitar os resultados pesquisados, onde estou errando no código a seguir?

```
    $conexao =mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$bank);
    $pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? $_GET['pagina'] : 1 ;


   $consulta1 ="SELECT * FROM registro_clientes";
   $qrTotal  =mysqli_query($conexao,$consulta1) or die(mysqli_error());
   $numTotal =mysqli_num_rows($qrTotal);
   $quantidade = 2;

   $totalPagina=ceil($numTotal/$quantidade);

   $inicio = ($quantidade * $pagina) - $quantidade;


       if(mysqli_connect_errno($conexao)){
           echo "erro conect hen";
           }else{

                 if(isset($_GET['buscar'])&& isset($_GET['onde'])){

                   $nome = $_GET['buscar'];
                   $bairro = $_GET['onde'];
               $consulta = "SELECT * FROM registro_clientes 
               WHERE nome_cliente LIKE '%$nome%' AND bairro LIKE '%$bairro%' 
               ORDER BY preferencial ASC 
               LIMIT $inicio, $quantidade ";
               $executar = mysqli_query($conexao,$consulta);

               $total = mysqli_num_rows($executar);

                    echo  "Encontrado     ".$total. "     resultado(s):";
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "<hr>";                        

               while ($ln=mysqli_fetch_array($executar))
```

Answer (score 0):

- É melhor que você use o `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM registro_clientes;` para descobrir quantos registros existem. A query é muito menor e mais peformatica.
- Não entendi direito a conta que você quis usar, mas isso deve funcionar melhor. `$inicio = ($pagina - 1) * $numTotal`

Comment: obrigado Daniel por me responder, eu fiz seguindo tutoriais, talvez eu não esteja dizendo corretamente o que eu quero dizer. Então eu fiz o que você me falou, ok, ele funcionou, ta ok,

Comment: só que agora eu me deparei com outra questão que não ta nas linhas de código, que é a paginação, voce pode me apontar onde eu to errando nessa questão, segue abaixo o código:                                                                     echo '<a href="?pagina=1">  primeira pag  </a> - ';
     
       for($i = 1; $i <= $totalPagina; $i++){
      
 if($i == $pagina)
 echo $i;
  else
 echo"<a href='resultados.php?pagina=$i'>". $i. "</a>";  
      
      }
      
    echo" - <a href=\"?pagina=$totalPagina\">  ultima pag  </a> ";